# Facing HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type from JAX-RS client when using MessageBodyReader

Tags: rest, jax-rs

I am new to RESTFul wit JAX-RS and learning. I am facing problem only when i request from JAX-RS client application. Its working fine from post plugin. But when i am changing the @Consumes("myformat/xml") with "application/xml" then its working. Below is the code.

MessageBodyReader:

```
package com.memorynotfound.jaxrs.chunked;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

@Provider
@Consumes("myformat/xml")
public class UserMessageBodyReader implements MessageBodyReader<User> {

    public boolean isReadable(Class<?> arg0, Type arg1, Annotation[] arg2, MediaType arg3) {

        if (arg0.equals(User.class))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public User readFrom(Class<User> arg0, Type arg1, Annotation[] arg2, MediaType arg3,
            MultivaluedMap<String, String> arg4, InputStream arg5) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
        return new User(1, "Jphn Doe");
    }

}
```

Resource:

```
package com.memorynotfound.jaxrs.chunked;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;

@Path("/users")
public class UserResource {

    @POST
    @Consumes("myformat/xml")
    public User getUser(User user) {
        return user;
    }

}
```

Client code:

```
package com.restfulexample.client.messagebodyreader;

import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Entity;

public class MessageBodyReader {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();

        User user = new User(1, "Jphn Doe");
        User postedUser = client.target("http://localhost:9090/message-body-reader/api/users").request("myformat/xml")
                .post(Entity.xml(user), User.class);

        System.out.println(postedUser.getId() + " " + postedUser.getName());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution with the below code...

Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient().register(UserMessageBodyReader.class)
                .register(UserMessageBodyWriter.class);

We have to register both MessageBodyReader and Writer with the client.